# Google Developer Account

Tags: android, google-play

II've started to develop games for the giggle play store, and I'm a bit confused in the developer console. It requires you tocreate 5 achievements. Why is it that Google requires this? I can understand there use as maybe a way to track progress, but what if I don't want them in my application. I don't want to troll people if they check up on achievements and see that they never get one nor ever will. I just want to be able to not have them. Maybe just award all 5 when the first log in to Google? I don't want to have to deal with them. Is there a specific reason Google requires these?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't Google tech support. This question is off topic here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about age limits, and legal advice. Stack Overflow cannot provide information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've found what I believe to be the answer. It says in that same line If you are between 13-17 it is for the SOLE purpose of google play purchasing. So google wallet cannot be used for earning money if you are below the age of 18. So if you want to make any money off of ads or purchasing of any sort you must either be above 18 or put the app up through somebody who is at least 18 or above.